# How to Copy Multiple files in Azure Data Lake based on Last Modified Date only without considering the Time HH:MM:SS

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

[image]

Hello I am trying to create a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that picks data from ADLG2 based on the last modified date.

The issue is that whenever multiple data are added to a particular destination there is usually a different in Seconds or minutes which is affecting the pipeline making it pipe only one file.

I want to consider only the date when using the Get Metadata and ignoring the timestamp. This way any data that falls in the same day the pipeline should be able to pick it.

Thanks

I used the Get Meta Data to get the last modified date and I was able to get the data but it was giving me only one file. What I was expecting is multiple files since they are all uploaded in the same date but ignor the timestamp.

Comment: Sorry but show us your steps so we can help properly. We’re flying blind here.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to consider only the date when using the Get Metadata and ignoring the timestamp. This way any data that falls in the same day the pipeline should be able to pick it.

Without timestamp it is not possible. because it should be in `(yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` this format as per below:

[image]

To your scenario you need all the files with same modified date in get metadata to do that you need to fetch files from start date timestamp to next day timestamp. to create it you can use Dynamic expression.

- First I created string parameter for date as below:

[image]

- You can yose below dynamic expression for start date and end date to create correct timestamp value for the string date value.

```json
Start Date : @formatDateTime(concat(split(pipeline().parameters.date,'/')[2],'-',split(pipeline().parameters.date,'/')[1],'-',split(pipeline().parameters.date,'/')[0]),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')

End Date : @adddays(formatDateTime(concat(split(pipeline().parameters.date,'/')[2],'-',split(pipeline().parameters.date,'/')[1],'-',split(pipeline().parameters.date,'/')[0]),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ'),1)
--As end date should be next day
```

[image]

**It will take it in correct format and produce the output accordingly:
Input:**

[image]

**Output:**
[image]